# ANSI C - Count words and letters per line

Tags: c, text, count, ansi-c

I'm working on a personal project,but I have no idea how to do it:

- Count the words (each word costs $5 usd)
- Count the letters per word (if the word has less than 4 letters costs $4 USD, if is more than 4 letters it costs $5 USD)

  ---

This is my code so far:

```
char txt[50];

printf("Introduce a text: ");
scanf("%s",&txt);
for(i=1; i <= N; i++){
  fgets(txt,50,stdin);
}
```

Example of the expected output:

```
The cost is: $24 USD
```

I just dont know whats next, any help will be appreciated :) Thanks.

**More explanation:**

Say a user introduces a text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameth
```

So the program will look into each word, for example "Lorem" it has 5 letters, it will cost that word $5 USD.. now "ipsum" has 5 letters too, so another $5 USD.. "dolor" has 5, so other $5 USD... "sit" has 3 letters so lets sum up another $4 USD... "ameth" has 5, so $5 more...

The cost of this text is: $24 USD

Comment: First, describe how you would do this without a computer. Go into extreme detail, assume that the person doesn't know what a "word" is. Assume the person doesn't even know how to count the number of letters in a word.

Comment: You're going to want to research `strtok`

Comment: Just added more info :) Thanks

Comment: Ruby working program: `$_.split.inject(0) {|m,w| m + (w.length < 4 ? 4 : 5)} while gets` the question explicitly say C, so why did you? "pyton" really? ... ....

Answer (score 5):

What I would do in general terms:

1. Load the text - apart from error handling/input validation/overflow, you've got the right idea.
2. Tokenize the input into words using `strtok()` from `string.h`. Look it up, but it basically uses a delimiter(s) provided by you to split your input string (probably `txt`) into the desired tokens (an example - delimiter = "space" would split the input into each "simple" word where space is the only demarcation of a new word). Its output on each iteration (you call `strtok` in a loop generally) is the next token or "word".
3. Use `strlen` on each resulting cstring produced by `strtok` to count the size of each "word"

YES I KNOW WE HATE cplusplus.com, but this example seems OK on initial glance (confirmed - works):

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The reason why the tokenizing syntax looks a little weird is because:

[Description of STRTOK function and explanation of its syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)

WARNING: As is evident from the link, `strtok` MODIFIES the original string that you pass it. Therefore, if you want to keep it for some other glorious purpose, keep a safe copy somewhere.

Comment: Hey thanks alot!, let me try your codes and will get back here, hope you can help a bit more if needed :)

Comment: @Daniel No problem, just come back if you need help